# How to pass value to a modelform_factory function from djnago templates

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, formset

In my template, I have a loop to display each row in a table, each row has a couple of input fields from the formset function I created. I'm facing an issue where I want to pass an id for each row I'm looping in so that I can control the data inserted in my database, but the problem is how can I detect the id of each row I'm in, to insert each row separately?

```
{% for products in products_info %}
 <tr>
     <td>{{issuance_formset.checked}}</td>
     <td><a href="#" class="open-modal" data-url="{% url 'shop:item_modal' products.id %}">{{products.item.name}}</a></td>
     <td>{{issuance_formset.factory}}</td>
 <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

what I want is to pass the products.id for each row from each loop iteration along with the form request. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use forloop.counter?

```
{% for products in products_info %}
 <tr id="row_{{forloop.counter}}">
     <td>{{issuance_formset.checked}}</td>
     <td><a href="#" class="open-modal" data-url="{% url 'shop:item_modal' products.id %}">{{products.item.name}}</a></td>
     <td>{{issuance_formset.factory}}</td>
 <tr>
{% endfor %}
```

There's a few variables set by the for loop along this line.  See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for more!

Comment: and how to reach the counter value in my views class?